# How to get data between tag by using php

Tags: php, regex

if I have input like this `<n>336197298</n>` how do I get the number between the tag by using php programming. I try to use regular expression but I can't find the method for this task.
Could you please help me .

Comment: is that an HTML input? is that a string?

Comment: maybe you have to use JavaScript

Comment: It's 2013. Don't use a regex to parse XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think regular expression is best try this method,

```
function get_content( $tag , $content )
{
    preg_match("/<".$tag."[^>]*>(.*?)<\/$tag>/si", $content, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
}
```

Comment: if I have one more tag, it doesn't work such as
< n >1234< /n >...
< n >567< /n >...
< n >7755< /n >..
it return just 1234
How to get all of it?

Comment: use  `preg_match_all` instead of `preg_match` and all number put into $matches array ( user var_dump after it to see $mathes array ) here documation : www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: thank you so much I try
preg_match_all("/<".$tag.">[^<]*(.*?)<\/$tag>/si", $content, $matches,PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
This is work!!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is no nesting of tags, the regex you need is

```
n >(.*?)<
```

This captures exactly what is between `n >` and `<`, but it makes many assumptions that you weren't clear about.  Is it always `n` or can it be something else?  Is there always a single space between the tag name and `>`?  Are you worried about matching the tags?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a regex for this.

See [xml_parse_into_struct](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xml-parse-into-struct.php):

```
<?php
$simple = "<para><note>simple note</note></para>";
$p = xml_parser_create();
xml_parse_into_struct($p, $simple, $vals, $index);
xml_parser_free($p);
echo "Index array\n";
print_r($index);
echo "\nVals array\n";
print_r($vals);
?>
```

Output:

```
Index array
Array
(
    [PARA] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 2
        )

    [NOTE] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

)

Vals array
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [tag] => PARA
            [type] => open
            [level] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [tag] => NOTE
            [type] => complete
            [level] => 2
            [value] => simple note
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [tag] => PARA
            [type] => close
            [level] => 1
        )

)
```